# Django createsuperuser not working with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-authentication

I'm trying to create a superuser for my django app and I'm getting very strange behaviour. Hopefully someone can enlighten me.

```
./manage.py createsuperuser
```

When I run this and go through the prompts, it finally says `Superuser created successfully.` But then when I check in PostgreSQL by doing `select * from auth_user;` there are no rows, so clearly it didn't work!

I also tried it through the shell by running

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
me = User.objects.db_manager('default').create_superuser(credentials...)
me.save()
```

I get the exact same thing through this. The object appears to be saved successfully, I can even check again `User.objects.all()` and it is there. However, the psql shell still tells me that the `auth_user` table is empty.

So I thought, okay, maybe it's something to do with postgres permissions and django going to the wrong db. I set all the permissions `pg_hba.conf` to `md5` and made sure my django settings matched the right login credentials for the database, restarted everything a couple of times but still nothing.

Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
Okay thanks for your help guys. I think I must have screwed something up with my postgres database because I just rebuilt everything from scratch and it works normally now.

Comment: Try doing me.is_superuser ... I don't have a django shell in front of me at the moment (or I'd answer vs comment), but I think auth_user stores individual auths (e.g. can user X create, delete, or edit model Y) and the User model stores the overriding boolean is_superuser ...

Comment: Is it creating the other (session etc) tables correctly?Are you sure you are checking the correct database?

Comment: me.is_superuser() returns True. So are you saying the actual user model is stored in a different table to auth_user? Edit - And yes, I'm able to create other models just fine. Haven't checked sessions yet.

Comment: You can create models, but can you insert data into your tables? Your PostgreSQL user might have CREATE privileges only but not INSERT.

Comment: which version of Django are you using? If 1.5+, are you overwriting [`AUTH_USER_MODEL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)? If yes, then your user data will not be inserted to `auth_user` but in your own custom table.

Comment: The postgres user I'm testing with has the default superuser privileges `Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication`. And I'm pretty sure I'm not overriding the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. It's a very clean, new install of django 1.7.4. I'm also thinking, if it was a permissions issue, wouldn't that throw some sort of exception, instead of just silently failing like this?

Comment: weird... I was thinking user_model was stored in a different table, but that's not the case (I was thinking of auth_user_user_permissions).  Can you list what tables you do have?  And in my vanilla django app (i.e. I just did django-admin.py startproject so and then ran syncdb to create superuser), auth_user is behaving as you expect, though I was lazy and used the sqlite option